# Read JSON data from non-RESTful API with ajax in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript, ember-data

I'm building a little hacker news reader for a learning project where the API I'm reading is a bit non-standard (so ember-data is out of the question unless someone knows how to shoehorn it).

List of items are here: http://node-hnapi.herokuapp.com/news while an individual item is like this: http://node-hnapi.herokuapp.com/item/6696691

Here's what I have going on so far: http://jsbin.com/OFeCoR/22/edit?html,js,output

```
App = Ember.Application.create()

baseURL = "http://node-hnapi.herokuapp.com"
newsURL = "/news"
itemURL = "/item/"

App.Items = Ember.Object.extend(  
  id: ""
  title: ""
  url: ""
  points: ""
  user: ""
  time_ago: ""
  comments_count: ""
  slug: (->
    @get("id")
  ).property("id")
)

App.Items.reopenClass 
  all: ->
    Ember.$.getJSON(baseURL + newsURL).then (response) ->
      items = []
      response.forEach (n) ->
        items.push App.Items.create(n)
      items     

App.Router.map ->
  @resource "items", ->
    @route "item",
      path: ":slug"

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  beforeModel: ->
    @transitionTo "items"

App.ItemsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    App.Items.all()

App.ItemsItemRoute - Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    itemID = App.Items.findProperty("id", params.id)
    Ember.$.getJSON((baseURL + itemURL + itemID).then (response) ->
      item = []
      response.forEach (i) ->
        item.push App.Item.create(i)
      item
    )
```

Basically I'm trying to grab the ID from an "item" in items to use it for the slug and in the ItemsItemRoute, shove it into the URL to get the individual item properties. I think this is where I'm going wrong (ItemsItemRoute).

I think it might make sense to only get the individual item data when a link / action is clicked instead all of them from the start. Any thoughts on how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `App.ItemsItemRoute` have some errors:

```
# you are using minus (-) this is a assigment and a equals (=) is needed
App.ItemsItemRoute - Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    # App.Items.findProperty don't exist and params.id isn't present just params.slug because you mapped your route with path: ":slug"
    itemID = App.Items.findProperty("id", params.id)
    Ember.$.getJSON((baseURL + itemURL + itemID).then (response) ->          
      item = []
      # this will return just one item, no forEach needed
      response.forEach (i) ->
        item.push App.Item.create(i)
      item
    )
```

I updated to the following:

```
App.ItemsItemRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->    
    Ember.$.getJSON(baseURL + itemURL + params.slug).then (response) ->
      App.Items.create(response)
```

And added a {{link-to}} in each item to be able to transition to `ItemsItemRoute`

This is the updated jsbin http://jsbin.com/OlUvON/1/edit

Comment: Ah, good catch on the typos...

This is very concise, thank you. I suppose params.slug works because item is under the items route?

Comment: Because it's under the item route.  You couldn't use it in the items route.  The params are parsed from the url and passed into the route that has the dynamic slug.  Just to let you know, you can't have any other routes under a route.  You can add resources under resources, but a route is a dead end.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to have a resource that's separate from the parents resource you should change your router to something like this:

```
App.Router.map ->
  @resource "items"
  @resource "item",
    path: ":slug"
```

But if you just wanna grab the already fetched model and keep the same look, there is no reason to refetch the data since you've already gotten it, you should just be using modelFor and grabbing it from the parent resource

http://jsbin.com/eCOzOKe/1/edit

```
App.ItemsItemRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    itemsModel = @modelFor("items")
    item = itemsModel.findProperty("id", params.slug)
    item
```

Additionally, you don't need to use the word slug, you can just use `:id` and remove the computed property from your model that just returns the `id` as `slug`.

Comment: There are a few different data points in the /item/ resource (comments in particular). Good point on the slug. I had that in there with the original idea of dasherizing the title as the route, but that could end up being pretty long.